# How to escape special characters in header of curl command

Tags: curl, http-headers, escaping

I want to curl a url through REST call. The call requires a authorization header to be sent along with it. The authorization header contains a !(apostrophe) character in it. when I send it it throws the following  error.

*-bash: !FeTSs: event not found*

**curl -H "X-Med-Authorization:3b7N/FNDcEVX&v09n8O6jeUz9l!FeTSs;cSf3wz/mDsvzKGX" -X GET http://192.168.1.2:8383/dcCore/health/**

I searched out there are answer to escape special characters in post data but not in headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this problem myself and got fairly frustrated trying to find a solution until I discovered that backslashing the offending characters is good enough!

So:

```
curl -H "X-Med-Authorization:3b7N/FNDcEVX&v09n8O6jeUz9l!FeTSs;cSf3wz/mDsvzKGX" -X GET http://192.168.1.2:8383/dcCore/health/
```

Just needs to become:

```
curl -H "X-Med-Authorization:3b7N/FNDcEVX&v09n8O6jeUz9l\!FeTSs;cSf3wz/mDsvzKGX" -X GET http://192.168.1.2:8383/dcCore/health/
```

You can check that the correct header is being sent by viewing the output when cURL is run with the `--verbose` flag. In that I see:

```
> X-Med-Authorization:3b7N/FNDcEVX&v09n8O6jeUz9l!FeTSs;cSf3wz/mDsvzKGX
```

No backslash. Boom. I suspect you've found a solution to this by now but hopefully this helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$''` form to pass arguments as-is. E.g.

> curl -H $'appCookie=x-Abc!123' http://localhost

Ref: [wiki.bash-hackers.org](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) and [www.gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)